# SQL Group by within another group by

Tags: sql, impala

I have currently a problem where I need to find a count of groups within a group. However, I want to create on line for the encompassing group and concatenate the smaller group within a string.

The following table shows the situation I am currently facing:

```
----------------------------------------
Timestamp           ID             Member
----------------------------------------
1                   1              A
1                   1              B
1                   2              A
1                   2              B
1                   2              C
2                   1              A
2                   2              A
2                   2              A
2                   2              C
----------------------------------------
```

Now I want to find for each timestamp, how many (distinct) members of each ID are in the table, i.e., the result should look like this:

---

```
Timestamp           MemberIDCount
----------------------------------------
1                   1:2,2:3
2                   1:1,2:2
----------------------------------------
```

i.e., the format of the string is:

```
[ID]:[count(distinct(member)],...
```

I know, that you can solve this with two consecutive group bys (i.e., first on timestamp and ID to count members and the on timestamp for the string concatenation). However, I hope that there is a smarter solution, since I have to apply that to a large dataset and dont want to have to execute 2 group bys. I work with Cloudera Impala, but solutions in other SQL languages are also appreciated.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using `group by` twice and `group_concat()`.  I don't have Impala on hand, but something like this should work:

```
select timestamp,
       group_concat(concat_ws(':', member, cnt))
from (select timestamp, member, count(*) as cnt
      from t
      group by timestamp, member
     ) tm
group by timestamp
order by timestamp;
```

Comment: Reference: https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-5-x/topics/impala_group_concat.html